# create a tale to take in different aspects

Tags: prepositional-phrases

> We are self-centered interpreters of all incoming information. At any given moment, we may note only one aspect of a current flow of information, depending on our view of ourselves, our attention, and our emotional state in a specific situation. Later, we may note still other aspects of a similar flow of information. Then, when an attempt to recall the second moment is confused with the memory of the original moment, our brain starts to create a tale to ***take in*** different
> aspects of both the original situation and the second moment. We suddenly confuse the two episodes, as we begin to put the two sets of events into some kind of memory mixture.

'take in' is a phrasal verb here or is it separable like prepositional phrases(in+noun)?

Comment: from google:  *phrasal verb of take
1.
include or encompass something.*

Comment: It should be evident from context (not making any sense) that "in different aspects of both the original situation and the second moment" isn't a prepositional phrase, so "in" goes with "take".

Comment: *Take in* means absorb, or process internally.